# How to change office tab's backcolor in a MFC multi document project?

Tags: c++, mfc

1. Use Vistual Studio 2012 or up
2. Create a MFC project
3. In the Wizard, set to Multiple document project
4. Set to Office style
5. Run it.
6. Click new button to create some empty documents.
7. Now I want to know how to change tab's header backcolor in these empty documents?

Comment: It looks like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable auto-color in MainFrm.cpp

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(...)
{
    //...
    mdiTabParams.m_bAutoColor = FALSE; // set to FALSE to disable auto-coloring of MDI tabs
}
```

Perhaps you knew about that already! To change the tab's background color to something specific can be very tricky because it's all tied in to the selected theme. But you can do it, for example by the following method:

```
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB, &CMainFrame::OnAfxWmChangingActiveTab)

LRESULT CMainFrame::OnAfxWmChangingActiveTab(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CMFCTabCtrl* tab = (CMFCTabCtrl*)lParam;
    if (tab)
        tab->SetTabBkColor(wParam,RGB(255,0,0));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the tab colors by the following code:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if(-1 == CMDIFrameWndEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct))
        return -1;
....
    CMFCTabCtrl& MFCTabCtrl = GetMDITabs();
    MFCTabCtrl.EnableAutoColor(FALSE);
....
```